# Matlab large matrix multiplication limit

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to run the following code below, but Matlab freezes when my matrix gets beyond 10,000 columns. What can I do to fix this?

```
X = load('iris.mtx');
[n,d] = size(X);
%X=14000x128 double
%form RBF over the data:
nms = sum(X'.^2); %nms becomes 14000x1
%here is where the crash begins, for a smaller data size, like 10000x128, this part wont freeze
K = exp(-nms'*ones(1,n) -ones(n,1)*nms + 2*X*X');
```

Is this a limitation that I just have to accept? I need to be able to use this for matrix that are much bigger than what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to this previously asked question about limitations in the size of Matlab matrices: [Matrix size limitation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328044/regarding-size-limitation-of-creating-a-matrix-in-matlab).

The only limitations are the limitations of your hardware.

Not knowing more about what you need to do I can't suggest much further reading. However, as the size of your matrices gets to be larger than you have memory for this question addresses the issue of optimizing your operations. [Efficient multiplication of very large matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420235/efficient-multiplication-of-very-large-matrices-in-matlab)